# Releasing the Global VM Lock in a C extension without using another function

Tags: c, ruby, multithreading

I don't understand why there's a need for another level of indirection when releasing or acquiring the GVL in Ruby C API.
Both `rb_thread_call_without_gvl()` and `rb_thread_call_with_gvl()` require a function that accepts only one argument which isn't always the case.
I don't want to wrap my arguments in a struct just for the purpose of releasing the GVL. It complicates the code's readability and requires casting from and to void pointers.
After looking into Ruby's threading code I found the [`GVL_UNLOCK_BEGIN`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L155)/[`GVL_UNLOCK_END`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L141) macros that matches Python's [`Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`/`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code) but I can't find documentation about them and when they are safe to use.
There's also the [`BLOCKING_REGION`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L155) macro is used within [`rb_thread_call_without_gvl()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L1287) but I'm not sure if it's safe to use it as a standalone without calling `rb_thread_call_without_gvl()` itself.

What is the correct way to **safely** release the GVL in the middle of the execution flow without having to call another function?

Comment: The API is designed so that your C code must explicitly declare its intent to run either with or without the GVL, and so that in the latter case, it cannot fail to reacquire the GVL before returning to Ruby.  This necessitates a function wrapping release of the GVL, running your code, and reacquisition of the GVL.  You must package your code into a function to be able to tell that launch function what to do.  And the API must therefore choose one or a small number of supported signatures for the user function, because each signature requires a separate launch function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ruby 2.x, there is *only* the `rb_thread_call_without_gvl` API. `GVL_UNLOCK_BEGIN` and `GVL_UNLOCK_END` are implementation details that are only defined in `thread.c`, and are therefore *unavailable* to Ruby extensions. Thus, the *direct* answer to your question is "there is no way to correctly *and* safely release the GVL without calling another function".

There was previously a "region-based" API, `rb_thread_blocking_region_begin`/`rb_thread_blocking_region_end`, but this API was deprecated in Ruby 1.9.3 and removed in Ruby 2.2 (see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/CAPI_obsolete_definitions for the CAPI deprecation schedule).

Therefore, unfortunately, you are stuck with `rb_thread_call_without_gvl`.

---

That said, there's a few things you could do to ease the pain. In standard C, converting between most pointers and `void *` is implicit, so you don't have to add a cast. Furthermore, using *designated initializer syntax* can simplify the creation of the argument structure.

Thus, you can write

```
struct my_func_args {
    int arg1;
    char *arg2;
};

void *func_no_gvl(void *data) {
    struct my_func_args *args = data;
    /* do stuff with args->arg... */
    return NULL;
}

VALUE my_ruby_function(...) {
    ...
    struct my_func_args args = {
        // designated initializer syntax (C99) for cleaner code
        .arg1 = ...,
        .arg2 = ...,
    };

    // call without an unblock function
    void *res = rb_thread_call_without_gvl(func_no_gvl, &args, NULL, NULL);
    ...
}
```

Although this doesn't *solve* your original problem, it does at least make it more tolerable (I hope).

Answer (score 5):

> What is the correct way to safely release the GVL in the middle of the
>   execution flow without having to call another function?

You must use the supplied API or whatever method you use will eventually break. The API to the GVL is defined in `thread.h`

```
void *rb_thread_call_with_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1);
void *rb_thread_call_without_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1,
         rb_unblock_function_t *ubf, void *data2);
void *rb_thread_call_without_gvl2(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1,
          rb_unblock_function_t *ubf, void *data2);
```

What you find in the header is an agreement between you the consumer of their API's and the author of the API's. Think of it as a contract. Anything you find in a `.c` in particular static methods and MACROS are not for consumption outside the file unless it's found in the header. The `static` keyword prevents this from happening, it's one of the reason it exists and it's most important use in C. The other items you mentioned are in `thread.c`. You can poke around in `thread.c` but using anything from it is a violation of the API's contract ie it's not safe and never will be.

**I'm not suggesting you do this** but the only way for you to do what you want is to copy portions of their implementation into your own code and this would not pass a code review. The amount of code you would need to copy out would likely dwarf anything you would need to do to use their API's safely.