# Ruby Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) - rb_thread_call_without_gvl

Tags: c, ruby, gil, ruby-c-extension

I am struggling to pass arguments to `rb_thread_call_without_gvl`. This is the simple code I am using.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ruby.h>
#include <ruby/thread.h>

VALUE summa(VALUE self, VALUE x)
{
    double result;
    result = NUM2DBL(x) + NUM2DBL(x);

    printf("The sum in C is %f\n", result);
    return DBL2NUM(result);
}


VALUE no_gvl(VALUE self)
{
    double arg = 3.0;
    double *ptr = &arg;
    rb_thread_call_without_gvl(summa, ptr, NULL, NULL);
    return Qnil;
}

void Init_csum()
{
    VALUE myModule = rb_define_module("MyModule");
    VALUE myClass = rb_define_class_under(myModule, "MyClass", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_method(myClass, "summa", summa, 1);
    rb_define_method(myClass, "no_gvl", no_gvl, 0);
}
```

I then try to call the extension from Ruby with the script `client.rb`:

```
require './csum'
obj = MyModule::MyClass.new # MyClass is defined in C
puts "The sum in R is " + obj.summa(7.0).to_s
puts obj.no_gvl
```

And finally my `extconf.rb`:

```
require 'mkmf'
extension_name = 'csum'
create_makefile(extension_name)
```

I am a beginner in C, but I need to create an extension that can use a library without the limitation of one single thread. See my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019643/ruby-fiddle-and-global-interpreter-lock-gil).

When I `make` the extension I receive a warning saying

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'VALUE (VALUE, VALUE)' to parameter of type 'void *(*)(void *)'
```

Although I understand what it says, I cannot see how to fix it. Should I just ignore it?
Also when I run `client.rb` I have a segmentation fault when it calls `obj.no_gvl`.

I am on Mac OSX 10.10.5 and I am using Ruby 2.0.0-p247 through `rbenv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven’t seen it already, [the source for `rb_thread_call_without_gvl` includes some documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_247/thread.c#L1231-L1315). (I’ve linked to the version that you’re using, but that’s a [pretty old Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/16/ruby-2-0-0-p648-released/), you should look at updating if possible. This API is the same in current versions at least up to 2.3.1.)

The function prototype looks like:

```
void *rb_thread_call_without_gvl(void *(*func)(void *), void *data1,
             rb_unblock_function_t *ubf, void *data2);
```

The function that is being called should accept a single `void *` argument and return `void *`, i.e. it is a plain C function, *not* a C function implementing a Ruby method as you have in your example. In fact it *can’t* implement a Ruby method as doing so would mean accessing structures protected by the GVL.

To use it you need to move the code you want to execute without the lock into a function with the correct interface, and that doesn’t use any of the Ruby API. Here is an example (based on your own) that creates a Ruby method that doubles the argument passed to it, and does the work without the GVL:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ruby.h>
#include <ruby/thread.h>

// The function that does the work, accepts void* and returns void*
void* doubleArg(void* x) {
    // Unpack the arg and cast back to double.
    double val = *(double*)x;
    double result = val + val;
    printf("The sum in C is %f\n", result);

    // If you wanted you could wrap up some data here to return to
    // Ruby land.
    return NULL;
}

// The function implementing the Ruby method
VALUE double_no_gvl(VALUE self, VALUE arg) {
    // First wrap up the input as a pointer.
    // You'll probably want to do some checking on the type of the 
    // argument here too.
    double argAsDouble = NUM2DBL(arg);
    double *ptr = &argAsDouble;

    // Now call the function without the GVL.
    // It might be worth looking into providing
    // an ubf function here too.
    rb_thread_call_without_gvl(doubleArg, ptr, NULL, NULL);
    return Qnil;
}

void Init_csum() {
    VALUE myModule = rb_define_module("MyModule");
    VALUE myClass = rb_define_class_under(myModule, "MyClass", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_method(myClass, "double_no_gvl", double_no_gvl, 1);
}
```

You can call it with a script like:

```
require './csum'
obj = MyModule::MyClass.new
obj.double_no_gvl(3.9)
```

Comment: Very clear thanks. Re: Ruby version. I need to use this version because it is embedded in the software (SketchUp) for which I am writing a plugin. Also, I think I better understand the issue in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245878/releasing-the-global-vm-lock-in-a-c-extension-without-using-another-function) question. I am now trying to return the result to Ruby. If my understanding is correct I need to return a `void *` and then cast it back to `double` in `double_no_gvl`.

Comment: @Rojj yes, but be careful about allocation. You shouldn’t return a pointer to a local variable to a calling function, as in the calling function the pointer will point to somewhere off the stack (and will likely be overwritten the next time you call a function). It _might_ work if you unpack it immediatley, but would be risky. Instead you’ll need to `malloc` some storage (and `free` it in the calling function), or possibly pass a pointer to a struct that contains the arguments you need and allows you to set the result in it (rather than returning the result).